# Field extension, why $i(k)=j(k)=k$?

Tags: field-theory

Let $(L,i)$ and $(M,j)$ two field extension of a field $K$. Let $$\varphi: L\longrightarrow  M$$ a field homomorphism. Let $k\in K$ and $\ell\in L$, why$$\varphi(k\cdot \ell)=\varphi(k)\cdot \varphi(\ell)=\varphi(i(k))\cdot \varphi(\ell)=j(k)\cdot \varphi(\ell)=k\cdot \varphi(\ell).$$

I agree that $\varphi\circ i=j$, what I don't understan is why $k=i(k)=j(k)$.

Comment: I think there is confusion in notation. Are you sure it's not $$\phi(k\cdot \ell)=\phi(i(k)\ell)=\phi(i(k))\phi(\ell)=j(k)\phi(\ell)=k\cdot \phi(\ell)\ \ ?$$

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see any difference with what I wrote excepted that you didn't wrote $\varphi(k\cdot \ell)=\varphi(k)\cdot \varphi(\ell)$, but you are right, in my course it's precisely written as you wrote, even if I don't understand the subtlety, to me it's exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you have to notice that $k\in K$ and $\ell\in L$, and thus, when you wrote $k\cdot \ell$ it's of course not the law "multiplication" since these are two elements of different field. In fact $\cdot $ define an action of ring on $L$ by $$k\cdot \ell =i(k)\ell$$ and if I denote $*$ the multiplication over $L$, then $$k\cdot \ell =i(k)*\ell$$ has sense since $i(k)\in L$ and $\ell\in L$ too.

Now, as we talk previously,
$$\varphi(k\cdot \ell)=\varphi(k)\cdot \varphi(\ell)$$
has a priori no sense since $\varphi(k)\in M$ and $\varphi(\ell)\in M$ and that $\cdot $ is an action $K\times L\longrightarrow L$. So to write things properly, you have to prove that $\varphi$ is $K-$linear, which mean that : $$\varphi(k\cdot_L \ell)=k\cdot_M \varphi(\ell)$$
where I denote $\cdot _L$ the action $K\times L\longrightarrow L$ and $\cdot _M$ the action $K\times M\longrightarrow M$.

(I hope you remark that $\cdot_L$ define an external law on the $K-$vector space $L$ and $\cdot _M$ an external law on the $K-$vector space $M$... It's in fact what we want to prove). So, to prove it,
$$\varphi(k\cdot \ell)=\varphi(i(k)*_L\ell)\underset{\varphi\ homomorphism}{=}\varphi(i(k))*_M\varphi(\ell)=j(k)*_M\varphi(\ell)=k\cdot _M\varphi(\ell).$$

I of course denoted $*_L$ the multiplication in $L$ and $*_M$ the multiplication in $M$. Now, you have to notice that usually, we don't write the multiplication law, i.e. we write $ab$ despite of $a*_L b$, then, if we use this convention, we get
$$\varphi(k\cdot \ell)=\varphi(i(k)\ell)\underset{\varphi\ homomorphism}{=}\varphi(i(k))\varphi(\ell)=j(k)\varphi(\ell)=k\cdot _M\varphi(\ell),$$

do you understand ?

Comment: Great, I think it's more clear (I have to think a little bit more about it). Last thing: how do you know that $k\cdot \ell=i(k)\ell$ ?  (because I didn't mention this anywhere).

Comment: what else ?  You have an application that identify elements of $K$ as element of $L$ (since $i$ is an injection, otherwise, it won't be defined), the natural way to define $k\cdot \ell$ is of course as $i(k)\ell$.